# Directory.CreateDirectory Exception

Tags: c#

i am using `Directory.CreateDirectory("\\\\MyShared\\Pics\\NewFolder")` to create a new folder in the directory `\\MyShared\Pics` and i am getting an exception

```
Access to the path '\\MyShared\Pics\NewFolder' is denied.
```

i gave full control permission to `Everyone` for the shared folder '\MyShared'.
and i have also added `<identity impersonate="true"/>` in the Web.config

Note that `Directory.Exists("\\\\MyShared\\Pics")` returns `true`;

what am i missing?

Comment: Depending on what the actual problem is, superuser.com could also help you :)

Comment: Just a side note, you can use @ to avoid this ugly double slashes in strings :)

Comment: have you granted share permissions as well as NTFS permissions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below settings 
Go to properties --> Sharing --> Advanced Sharing --> Permissions