# Handle UnauthorizedAccessException When Directory.CreateDirectory() Run

Tags: c#

I have a method that is helps to Create a Directory ifNotExist and Save the path of the File ,...
Now I have a little problem, There is an Exception casted when `Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);` Runs. and I can't still get it right. I would like to know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it. Anyone Subjections is welcome. Thanks

Here is My Method:

```
protected void ASPxUpload_FileUploadComplete(object sender, DevExpress.Web.FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsValid)
        {
            String savepath = String.Format("{0}{1}\\", MapPath(@"~\TicketUploads\"), Session["lastcallid"]);
            if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);
            }
            String savefile = String.Format("{0}{1}", savepath, e.UploadedFile.FileName);
            e.UploadedFile.SaveAs(savefile);
            String urlPath = String.Format("{0}{1}\\{2}", @"~\TicketUploads\", Session["lastcallid"], e.UploadedFile.FileName);
            fault_detail fltdet = session.GetObjectByKey<fault_detail>(Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastcallid"]));
            fltdet.hasattachment = "Y";
            fltdet.AttachUrl = urlPath;
            fltdet.Save();
        }
    }
```

For more details of What I trying to do: 
 It simple allows the web server to identify the ID of the log user. and With that ID, We should therefore create a folder in **Ticketuploads** Folder. Which is like we are trying to create 2 folders at the same time. That is why I use: `"{0}{1}\\"`

Comment: Suggestion: Please use `Path.Combine` instead of `String.Format`

Comment: Try to run it as admin.

Comment: @AmeyKamat, Thank for your reply. But I just have tried what you have said. I have an error user: `Session["lastcallid"]`  it says: Caanot convert from object to String.

Comment: @CodeJoy, I'm already running it as Administrator thanks.

Comment: @CodeJoy, here is the full Exception message: `An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: try this, if (!Directory.Exists(savepath))
            {Thread.Sleep(100);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath);
            }

Comment: @viveknuna, Thanks for your reply, But Still not Working. Here is an additional info on the Exception : `Additional information: Access to the path`

Comment: then definitely its related to permissions

Comment: @viveknuna, I could said that, but I have already setup the permission in the mainFolder. It also Seems that the path is not saving correctly. please have a look of my code again.

Comment: @MichealP. have you tried (string)Session["lastcallid"] Did it give you error?

Comment: Path.Combine(MapPath(@"~\TicketUploads\"), (string)Session["lastcallid"]);

Comment: Can you give an example of what appears in Session["lastcallid"]? Incase you get something that is forbidden in the Directory name by OS, there are chances you can get exception.

Comment: @AmeyKamat, yes I tried it, but still casting another Exception: `An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Admin.dll but was not handled in user code
`

Comment: @AmeyKamat, More info about the exception : `Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.`

Comment: @AmeyKamat, There is an Error when I add (string)Session...: `invalid '['` But please illustrat by what you mean by: **there are chances you can get exception** Thanks

Comment: @MichealP. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa493942(v=exchg.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this

```
string sessionVariable = Convert.ToString(Session["lastcallid"]); 

string path = Path.Combine(MapPath(@"~\TicketUploads\"), sessionVariable);
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}
```

**Also**

I have Add Administration Permission to the Folder. As a Local user with IIS System. user Add Example: `IIS_IUSRS(Username\IIS_IUSRS)` That's it.

Comment: The `UnauthorizedAccessException was handle` still casting. May it need permission but I also tried this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802000/directory-createdirectory-exception](`Go to properties --> Sharing --> Advanced Sharing --> Permissions`) Stiil Not Working for me.

Comment: @MichealP. Can you give value of `Session["lastcallid"]` for which you are getting exception

Comment: `Session["lastcallid"]` = 1250057. It simple allows the webserver to identify the ID of the log user. and With that ID, We should therefore create a folder in `Ticketuploads` Folder. Which is like we are trying to create 2 folders at the same time. That is why I use: `"{0}{1}\\"`

Comment: @MichealP.the above code worked. The only change in my code is `string sessionVariable = Convert.ToString(1250057); string path = Path.Combine(@"E:\TicketUploads\", sessionVariable);`

Comment: you are write, This Solves. I went to look for an permission of the application setup. and I found out that The Whole folder did not allow user to add any subfolders. Also, by Converting my Path to string, I see the root read clear and well! Thanks for everything.